# How to convert a l-value tuple type to value tuple type?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, type-traits

Any type traits can help to convert a l-value tuple type to a value tuple type. For example, convert `std::tuple<int&, double&>` to `std::tuple<int, double>`  by removing the references.

Answer (score 1):

For tuple instances (edited based on dyp's comment):

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> remove_tuple_ref(std::tuple<Ts&...> x)
{
    return {x};
}
```

Comment: Well you don't need the type trait any more... but this trick requires that all tuple types are references.

Comment: @dyp Wouldn't my previous edit deal with all tuple types being references?

Comment: Your original version could be expanded to deal with non-reference tuple elements. (As does the compressed version `template<class... Ts> std::tuple< std::remove_reference_t<Ts>... > remove_tuple_ref(std::tuple<Ts...> x) { return {x}; }`)

Comment: @dyp Sorry, I meant wouldn't my previous edit deal with *not* all tuple types being references? I don't see how the "expanded" example is different from my original answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was confused by the revisions.